# Using the -d test operator in perl

Tags: perl

I'm going through someone's old code and I came across this statement:

```
$tmpStr = "/some/file/location/";

if(-d $tmpStr){
   printf("1");
}else{
   printf("2");
}
```

I'm confused about what the `-d` does... any help?

Comment: Thanks for the QUICK answers!  That seems to make sense!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-d` returns true if the following string is a directory.

See [`-X` in perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

Comment: It does a stat(2) syscall and if successful, checks the inode type for a directory.  The syscall can fail for other reasons, though, which people don't usually think of. For example, `-d "/foo/bar/glarch"` would be false if `bar` didn’t have the execute bit set for current users, even if `glarch` were indeed a directory.  Check `$!` or even `%!` afterwards for better detail.

Comment: @tchrist, for systems that support all of that I guess. (; But good point.

Comment: re: "Check `$!`": only if -d returns undef

Answer (score 5):

It checks whether the directory exists or not.  There are many more [file test operations](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) available, such as below:

```
   1. -r File is readable by effective uid/gid.
   2. -w File is writable by effective uid/gid.
   3. -x File is executable by effective uid/gid.
   4. -o File is owned by effective uid.
   5.
   6. -R File is readable by real uid/gid.
   7. -W File is writable by real uid/gid.
   8. -X File is executable by real uid/gid.
   9. -O File is owned by real uid.
  10.
  11. -e File exists.
  12. -z File has zero size (is empty).
  13. -s File has nonzero size (returns size in bytes).
  14.
  15. -f File is a plain file.
  16. -d File is a directory.
  17. -l File is a symbolic link.
  18. -p File is a named pipe (FIFO), or Filehandle is a pipe.
  19. -S File is a socket.
  20. -b File is a block special file.
  21. -c File is a character special file.
  22. -t Filehandle is opened to a tty.
  23.
  24. -u File has setuid bit set.
  25. -g File has setgid bit set.
  26. -k File has sticky bit set.
  27.
  28. -T File is an ASCII text file (heuristic guess).
  29. -B File is a "binary" file (opposite of -T).
  30.
  31. -M Script start time minus file modification time, in days.
  32. -A Same for access time.
  33. -C Same for inode change time (Unix, may differ for other platforms)
```

Answer (score 1):

That tests to see if that path is a directory. It's not string comparison.

This is a string comparison.

```
"Hello" ne "world"
```